# Memory performance of storing image as base64 in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage, base64

I'm fetching an image from server and display it on the cover screen of App. After I fetch the image I store it in UserDefaults as Base64 string. Everytime I open the app, I convert base64 string to Image again and show it as background image. Usually image sizes are 1-2mb in png formats. However, I'm not sure If It will be a problem in terms of memory (converting to base64 and vise-versa).

1-) Does converting base64 to image when everytime App opens cause any problem in terms of performance (Memory leak)?

2-) Is there any better approach to store image file?

Comment: Why are you converting to base 64? The image is data. Store the data. Done. (I wouldn’t store it in user defaults, but that’s not the point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Don't convert back and forth to base64. As Matt says, there's no reason for it. Your various storage options support binary data, so store it directly as binary data. (`Data`, even, since there are methods for writing Data objects to files in various formats.)

Step 2: Don't store large objects in `UserDefaults`. `UserDefaults` is intended to store small things like switch settings. Instead use a file, either in the Documents or the Caches directory.